# What exactly does launch4j do?

Tags: java, launch4j

If I am understanding correctly:

It will allow me to send an embedded `JRE` along with my `JAR` so that my jar works whether or not the user has Java installed on their computers.

I have never worked with it before so I thought I might ask before going on a steep learning curve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch4j does not embed the `JRE`. It is a wrapper for your `JAR` file which checks for an appropriate JRE installed on the target PC, and if it is not installed it will offer the user  to download it.